# Зависимость одного чекбокса от другого

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Здравствуйте.

Есть сложная в плане логики форма с чекбоксами. В JS не разбираюсь, потому использую готовые скрипты. Форма:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="checkbox" style="margin:-10px 0 0 25px;">
<input class="control" data-type="one" type="checkbox" name="razryad[]" value="1 разряд и выше" />1 разряд и выше<br />
<input class="control" data-type="two" type="checkbox" name="razryad[]" value="2 разряд и выше" />2 разряд и выше<br />
<input class="control" data-type="three" type="checkbox" name="razryad[]" value="Нет разряда" />Нет разряда
</div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid black; padding:10px; margin:3px 0 3px 0;">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two three" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #01" disabled />Дисциплина #01</td>
</tr>
</table><br />
</div>

<div class="block" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
<table> <!-- Единый взнос за обе дисциплины -->
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two three" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(2, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #02" disabled />Дисциплина #02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="check one" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(2, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #03" disabled />Дисциплина #03</td>
</tr>
</table><br />
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
<table> <!-- Единый взнос за три дисциплины -->
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two three" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(3, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #04" disabled />Дисциплина #04</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(3, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #05" disabled />Дисциплина #05</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two three" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(3, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #06" disabled />Дисциплина #06</td>
</tr>
</table><br />
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="check one two three" type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(4, 10, this)" value="Дисциплина #07" disabled />Дисциплина #07</td>
</tr>
</table><br />
</div>

<div><br />
<b>Итоговая стоимость:</b> <span id="r" name="def_sum">0</span> руб.<br />
<input type="hidden" id="def_sum" name="def_sum"><br />
</div>

<button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Посчитать стоимость участия</button>
```

Логика формы следующая:

1. Есть 3 основных чекбокса - разряды. Чекбоксы дисциплин в это время заблокированы. При выборе одного из разрядов разблокируются определенные дисциплины. За это отвечает скрипт:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

   window.onload=function(){
   $('.control').on('change',function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked')){
   $('.check.'+$(this).attr('data-type')).removeAttr('disabled');
   }else{
   $('.check.'+$(this).attr('data-type')).prop('checked',false).attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
   })
   }
   ```
2. При выборе чекбоксов дисциплин - их стоимость суммируютя JS-калькулятором. Код:

   ```
   var Calculator = {
   selectedGroups: [],
   sum: 0,

   isGroupSelected: function(groupId) {
       return this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId) != -1;
   },

   addSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
       if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
           this.changeSum(amount);
       }
       this.selectedGroups.push(groupId);
   },

   removeSelected: function(groupId, amount) {
       if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
           return;
       }
       var groupIndex = this.selectedGroups.indexOf(groupId);
       this.selectedGroups.splice(groupIndex, 1);
       if (!this.isGroupSelected(groupId)) {
           this.changeSum(-amount);
       }
   },

   onSelect: function(groupId, amount, elem) {
       if (elem.checked) {
           this.addSelected(groupId, amount);
       } else {
           this.removeSelected(groupId, amount);
       }
   },

   changeSum: function(amount) {
       this.sum += amount;
       this.showSum();
   },

   showSum: function() {
       document.getElementById ('r').innerHTML = this.sum;
       document.getElementById('def_sum').value = document.getElementById('r').innerHTML;
   }
   }
   ```

ЗАДАЧА: Нужен скрипт, чтобы при выборе дисциплин 04 и/или 06 автоматически отмечалась дисциплина 02. И при этом корректно работал калькулятор.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, у кого возникнет аналогичный вопрос:

```
var  array = {
"Дисциплина #04": "Дисциплина #02",
"Дисциплина #06": "Дисциплина #02"
}

$(".check").on('change', function() {
var select = $(this).val();
for (var key in array) {
if ($(this).prop("checked") && select == key ){
target = $("input[value='"+array[key]+"']");
if(!target.prop('checked')){
target.click();
}
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставить чекбокс: `$(".checkboxClass").prop("checked", true);`
2. Снять чекбокс: `$(".checkboxClass").prop("checked", false);`
3. Заблокировать: `$(".checkboxClass").prop("disabled", true);`
4. Разблокировать: `$(".checkboxClass").prop("disabled", false);`
5. Состояние: если галочка стоит то А иначе В

   `if ($(".checkboxClass").is(":checked")){
       console.log('Checked');
   } else {
       console.log('Unchecked');
   }`
6. Событие которое реагирует на перемену состояний:

   `$(".checkboxClass").on("change",function(){
       var $this = $(this); // $this - это будет ваш чекбокс
   });`

Уверен моих "сниппетов"("кусочков кода") достаточно что-бы написать нужную Вам логику.

Comment: Благодарю. Но, как я писал, в JS не разбираюсь. Каюсь, прозвучит нагло, но есть ли у вас возможность показать готовый скрипт?